# How to loop through subdirectories in a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I'm in a directory, dir1. Within that directory I have myscript.sh and a directory subdir1. subdir1 has several subsub directories, subsub1, subsub2, subsub3. Within each of those subsub directories is a bash script all named script2.sh, and I want to run each one of them.

First, I just want to make sure I can print all the subsub directories.
I have:

```
    for dir in /subdir1/*/ ; do
      echo $dir
    done
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to `man bash` and search for "globstar", as well as `man find`. Also, read about creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to do that for this question would be to include commands that you used to generate the test environment where your script excerpt failed. As it stands, there isn't nearly enough here to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could run them this way:

```
find subdir1 -type f -name "NAME_OF_YOUR_SCRIPT.sh" -exec {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to run into issues if any of the directories have spaces or other special characters in the names.

Based on what you provided

```
for scriptfile in ./subdir/*/*script2.sh
do
/bin/sh $scriptfile
done
```

may work best for you.

To deal with spaces or other special characters in your directory names, you'll want to use find and pass the output to xargs.

Comment: this gives me a No such file or directory message.

Comment: @HanBrolo - that's why you need to provide a repeatable example that demonstrates the problem you're having. This answer could very well work, and if it doesn't, it's because of something you haven't told us.